# Serving Lazy Thumbnail Images from Azure Blob Storage - What is the overhead of Exists?

Tags: asp.net, azure, lazy-loading

I have a website where users upload images. These images are shown on various sections of the site with various thumbnail dimensions. Since the site is still under rapid development, I don't yet want to commit to a set number of thumb sizes. Thus I believe I should be generating thumbnails on a lazy basis.

Of the two options, which is the most performant way to do this:

1. When I go to serve the thumbnail, convert the dimensions into a canonical filename (like "bighouse-thumb-160x120"). Check if the file exists in blob storage using client.GetContainerReference(containerName).GetBlockBlobReference(key).Exists(); If it does not exist, generate it and save it.
2. When I go to serve the thumbnail, query my SQL database to see if the thumbnail exists. If it exists, get the blob URI from the DB and emit that as HTML. If it does not exist, generate it and update the SQL database.

I've used #2 in the past, but design-wise it is duplicating state which is bad. If querying azure for the existence of blobs is scalable, I'd rather do that. I don't really understand the threading model in Asp.Net. If I have 200 users requesting thumbs, will my azure Exists calls all happen in parallel? Even if they do, two round trips seem like a lot of overhead. I assume roundtripping the database is faster and lends itself more easily to generic caching solutions.

What is the right answer?

Comment: why not just immediately create the thumbmail on image change (upload, overwrite, delete) and assume it is always there ?

Comment: That creates a problem if I later add new thumbnail sizes that didn't exist when the image was uploaded. Thus the need for lazy generation.

Comment: It's really hard to say what would be best unless someone has compared these two methods.  Also, even if they have compared them, The results may be different in your environment based on your coding, the amount of memory on the system (if a query is fulfilled from cached data, it will be much faster), etc.  I would recommend creating a test of 100,000 iterations of both positive and negative tests for each proposed method, and see which takes the most time.

Comment: Even just a "we did it this way and perf was never a problem" experience would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the overhead, I would pre-generate thumbnails when you upload/store the image. This way you move the burden of generating thumbnails from something that is done many times (retrieving an image) to one that is much less often executed (storing an image).

Consider the following scenario, when you lazily generate thumbnails on the first view:

- Check for an existing thumbnail (is `false`, first view remember ;))
- Generate a thumbnail
- Store the thumbnail
- Send the thumbnail to the client

With pre-generated thumbnails the process is much shorter:

- Send the thumbnail to the client

Done.

With 'lazy generating' the check for existing can be expensive due to network overhead (on every hit!), generating the thumbnail can be hugely expensive memory- & CPU-wise and than you have to store it, with network overhead again. You can even offload generating the thumbnail(s) to a separate process, possibly started by queue messages, to take the burden of generating the images even further away from your webservers.

However, this brings up the question of what you should do when you introduce a new thumbnail/image size. When you pre-generate the thumbnails you can write a simple tool to create the new sizes and store them, and if you went the separate process route it's even simpler. Just upgrade the separate process, generate a queue message for every existing image and just let it do its work.

Comment: Also, it would be a better deployment workflow to spin up a new job that will process all the pre-existing images for resizing them. Batch jobs for the win